# how to find treeview node ans childnode

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview

I have to find some node and child node in a tree view.Below code is only find the main node of the tree view.Then how can I find the child node

```
foreach(var id in values)
{
TreeNode node =TreeView1.FindNode(Server.HtmlEncode(id.ToString()));
if(node!=null)
{
node.Checked = true;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
TreeNode node = TreeViewProducts.FindNode(nodeID);
foreach (var childNode in node.ChildNodes)
{

}
```